# Is my batch script to replace program files on startup with rmdir and xcopy not working properly?

Tags: boot, batch, batch-file, xcopy, rmdir

I'm trying to work my way around a program that's giving me some problems.

It has to fire up every day and do it's thing, but rarely does - losing data and breaking very frequently.

So to counter this, I've made a batch file that deletes the program files (the program lives and runs out of it's own folder on C: ) and then copies them over from another location every morning when the computer fires up to reset anything funky that might have happened the night before (corrupted files on shutdown / overwriting saves and the like)

```
xcopy /s /Y /K /H /i "C:\Users\Media PC\Documents\Batch\Master\Folder" C:\Program\Name\Folder
START C:\Program\Name\Folder\Program_V_12.exe
echo server started batch complete = %time% %date%>> "C:\log.txt"
```

However, on launching the program from time to time it won't load correctly, not displaying a splash screen and not loading the project. I wonder if there is something missing here... perhaps there are some files that aren't being copied over, or something that's missing. These files could be hidden, or there could be priveledges missing...

Is the above code the "best" way to delete the program files, reinstate them and launch the program?

Can you foresee any issues with this? Particularly with regards to file corruption, priveledges, ownership, hidden files etc...

Are my flags sweet and good?

Should there be a delay at all before the START command?

Are there any problems with running a batch such as this from shell/startup - is there a more optimal way to do this? I've noticed that running the file manually has never resulted in any kind of problem...

Thanks in advance - really just feeling this out to be honest. I'm pretty confident that a solid batch script will fix the issue, so the fact that issues are occuring to me indicates the batch isn't quite watertight or fit for purpose.

:)

Comment: For starters: . Make sure you killed the previous invocation of that program. If it is still running you won't be able to properly replace its files. The flags look OK (but you probably don't need/want the /K flag)

Comment: Thanks @Tonny - this runs on startup so definitely not a previous program running. Think I might keep /k as I remember some of the files this program uses are read only.

Comment: If you are running it at startup does it run at login of your user-account or before that. If the latter... Under which user-account does that script actually run? Does that account have access to your user-profile where the source is located. Does the script need to run with elevated permissions (UAC control) and if so, does that actually happen when run at startup? There is a lot regarding permissions that can mess things up here.

Comment: Thanks @Tonny that's solid. 

It's just in the directory that shell:startup takes me to. I'm not sure what that entirely means, but I would assume it runs with admin privs